# How can I use a variable of one yaml in another yaml using powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, yaml, azure-devops-pipelines

As I am new to yaml and powershell,Can someone please help me in understanding the way of using a variable of one Yaml in another one?

**Example Scenario:**

I have variable- **$a in abc.yml** under the folder-**Test1**,now I have to use the same **$a in bcd.yaml** under the folder -**Test2**.

How can I achieve this in powershell?

Comment: I think it might be useful if you provide more information about the use case, like how are you using powershell to call one or the other

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/azure-pipelines-variable-templates/azure-pipelines-variable-templates/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass params between yml files in Azure DevOps you have to specify a path to the template (the file you want to pass the param across to) and give the parameter a value.  Then in the second file also declare the parameter.

To make use of the param it in the second yaml you can use the ${{parameters.name}} construction:

Let's assume $a represents a directory path...

Example contents of abc.yml:

```
stages:
- stage: 'Passing param example'
  jobs:
  - template: ${{variables['System.DefaultWorkingDirectory']}}/bcd.yml
    parameters:
      param1_butuseanynameyoulike: $a
```

The in the bcd.yml:

```
parameters:
  - name: 'param1_butuseanynameyoulike'
    displayName: 'Parameter passed from original yaml file'
    type: string
    default: ''

jobs:
  - job: somename

    steps:
        - task: PowerShell@2
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              Get-ChildItem -Path ${{ parameters.param1_butuseanynameyoulike }}"
```